# Windows service for MySQL 5.7 suddenly won't start. Error 1067

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows-7-x64

I have had a MySQL5.7 master database on a Win7 machine that replicates to a Linux slave.

It seems that after working for about a month, the Windows service for MySQL 5.7 server can no longer start.  Running it from services.msc it gives Error 1067.

Here is the MySQL error log:

```
2018-04-03T19:25:18.722913Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-04-03T19:25:18.722913Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2018-04-03T19:25:18.738515Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.17-log) starting as process 3508 ...
2018-04-03T19:25:18.785323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-04-03T19:25:18.785323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-04-03T19:25:18.785323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-04-03T19:25:18.785323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-04-03T19:25:18.785323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2018-04-03T19:25:18.785323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-04-03T19:25:18.785323Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-04-03T19:25:18.800926Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 8M, instances = 1, chunk size = 8M
2018-04-03T19:25:18.800926Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-04-03T19:25:50.552217Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for reading partial data failed.
2018-04-03T19:25:50.552217Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 1048576 bytes at offset 2097152, but was only able to read 0
2018-04-03T19:25:50.552217Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
2018-04-03T19:25:50.552217Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Please let me know if more info is needed and thanks in advance for any help.

**Update (2018-04-04):**

Screenshot: [Windows Services for MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFNSt.png)

Screenshot: [Change to local account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyrbO.png)

Answer (score 0):

The service won't have sufficient privileges to start, if the service is NETWORK_SERVICE so grant FULL CONTROL or change to LOCAL SERVICE

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Santiago!  

I have updated my original post to include screenshots to try your suggestion - I still get the same behaviour.  

**My steps:**  
1. Run **services.msc** as Administrator.
2. Find MySQL service and change Log On properties to Local System account.
3. Re-start service; Get error message for 1067.
4. Reboot system & repeated steps 1-3.  Service now set to Local System for log on as, but still won't start & get error message for 1067.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post in my blog about it. [manejandodatos.es/error1067](http://www.manejandodatos.es/2015/3/solution-to-error-1067-cant-start-the-server-on-mysql)

This error occurs when the server is down, you modify the data dir. It is a problem with the user.